# TFS Sharepoint Website

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

We have a TFS server running in our environment.  If you open a browser to the hostname and /default.aspx on port 80 it will bring up the default sharepoint site.
I would like to know where the calendar data is being stored for this site.  I have looked in the inet folder and although the site in the defaultsite directory has an app_data folder, it is simply populated with the .Net Framework Membership tables.

I am using TFS2010.
Does anyone know where the database is that stores this calendar data?

Thanks for any and all replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be stored in SharePoint's content database.  Typically called WSS_Content.

The below screenshots show where you find that info in SharePoint Central Admin (note: this is for SharePoint 2013, but it's probably similar for older versions of SharePoint)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In the TFS SQL Server there is a database for configuration and one for the collection.  In the wss folder of the default website there is a mdf in the app_data folder, however it does not hold that information.  I haven't found any data containers named wss_content.

Comment: the Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_Collection databases contain the TFS Data.  The calendars in SharePoint are not TFS Data but SharePoint data and are stored in the SharePoint database(s) which are separate from TFS.  It's possible your SharePoint install is pointing to databases on a different server, the only way to know for sure is to go into SharePoint Central Admin and check where the Content Database is pointing to.